# Blackberry App submit ( Spanish Language )

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

The Blackberry App World is telling me that :

Release 1.0.0.0 does not specify a English(en) bundle for device '8705g (Min. OS 6.0.0)'.

I have made the zip , and upload all .cod files well . But i don't know if i have forgotten some file i must make (releases.xml done too) .

The problem comes when i'm trying to submit an spanish bundle .

You can see it here :

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it , i must have rename the .cod package into blablabla_en.cod and blablabla_es.cod in 2 bundles.

Answer (score 0):

i m not getting exactly `(spanish bundle)` that How this happen but don't need to add `release.xml` file.  just take `.cod & .jad fine` and make `zip` and upload it `with langauge English(en)`.